# parallax margin-top wont go under 0px

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Currently creating a parallax effect on an image. got the following jquery:

```
        $(window).scroll(function () {
        var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
          if(fromTop < 800) {
            $(".parallax").css('margin-top', '+' + (250 - fromTop / 2) + 'px');
          };
        });
```

HTML:

```
<img src="Images/Optimized.png" class="img-responsive center-block parallax" style="margin-top:250px"/>
```

i need the margin-top to go down to -30px.. however my code doesnt allow it to go below 0.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I had to remove the '+' in front of my variable so that it looks like:

```
    $(window).scroll(function () {
    var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      if(fromTop < 800) {
        $(".parallax").css('margin-top', (250 - fromTop / 2) + 'px');
      };
    });
```